# I need a pivot table of the pivot table I've created

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, measure

I have a fact table that covers several weeks of tasks in MS Project, and each week is timestamped with that week's week-ending date. I am trying to get the previous week's remaining work for certain tasks (they have a flag called Should Finish This Week set to TRUE).

I have a formula that enables me to create a pivot table that, when I manually sum the values column (it's basically a MIN of the previous week's remaining hours by assignment id), it gives me the result I want.

However, I cannot figure out how to "build this pivot table in DAX" so that I can summarize the resulting sum of hours by department. Right now, I just have the number of hours by task (assignment id) for last week.

Here's the formula:

```
Simple Min :=
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( DataMerge[PreviousWeekRemainingWork] ),
    AssignmentHistory[ShouldFinishThisWeek] = TRUE (),
    DataMerge[BestPercentComplete2] < 1,
    DataMerge[CompletedFLAG] = FALSE (),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Calendar'[Date], DataMerge[End of Week] )
)
```

And with that formula, I can output the following pivot table (this is just a small sample):

[image: Image of results pivot table sample]

The desire is to get a SUM of the Simple Min value by Department. I've tried all the tricks of PowerPivot that I know. Here' the latest iteration of a formula I tried, but the amounts by department are all incorrect, and the grand total is off by about 1200 to the high side.

```
HRS Remaining More Simple :=
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        DataMerge,
        DataMerge[ResourceDepartments_R],
        DataMerge[AssignmentId]
    ),
    [Simple Min]
)
```

Any help on this last formula would be greatly appreciated. When I manually sum the pivot table, I come up with ~4300 hours, which is the correct number, so I can verify the formula once given.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this? It's very difficult to answer this sort of thing without having some sample input/output nor relationship structure.